# How to output only the uv map without original picture in densepose?

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, motion-detection

I'm using Densepose in detectron2 .The type of output I get is as shown in the image below
[enter image description here][1]

But I want to get the output with black background like this
[enter image description here][2]

Is there a way to help me do this?
Thanks.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lo2uZ.jpg
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQ8Zh.png

Comment: Hello Aaron,
You may need to read up on creating minimal reproducible examples in your questions https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Your question is interesting, but contributors who spend time answering questions will likely need more to work with.